# Millions of particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Is there a proper way of doing this?been experimenting with particles but have noticed the more particles the slower blender gets I'm talking about 500000 to millions even with baking is still slow .

Comment: Particles are baked to RAM by default. This is normally faster, but with more particles, you may hit the limit where you simply don't have enough RAM. In this case, the system will start swapping RAM to disk, which slows things down, and disk cache will actually be faster, as Blender will write/read directly to/from disk, rather than having RAM swapped to and fro by the system. This also leaves enough RAM for the system and other applications. Probably not a full solution, hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Even after baking the location of each particle to reduce the calculations needed for each frame, there is a point where drawing X million particles Y times every second takes longer than 1 second.